# Operating on list of strings representing column names?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm currently trying to automate a data task that requires taking in a list of column names in string format, then summing those columns (rowwise). i.e., suppose there is some list as follows:

```
> list
[1] "colname1" "colname2" "colname3"
```

How would I go about passing in this list to some function like sum() in tidyverse? That is, I would like to run something like the following:

```
df <- df %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(new_var = sum(list))
```

Any suggestions would be greatly, greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: First, be careful using the word "list". In R a list is a specific type of data structure. Your example `list` (where list just means a series of items) looks like what R calls a vector. Second, I think what you want to achieve would be done using some variant of `dplyr::select` and `across`. It would help to see some real example data (from `df`) and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rowSums` here. For example:

```
library(dplyr)

mycols <- colnames(iris)[3:4]
mycols

[1] "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"
```

Then:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(new_var = rowSums(.[, mycols])) %>% 
  head()
```

Result:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new_var
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     1.6
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     1.6
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     1.5
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     1.7
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     1.6
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the vector of column names in `c_across`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(new_var = sum(c_across(list)))
df
```